# I am implementing volley for android but i am getting ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-volley

I am calling the Volley but there is a ClassCast exception occurring. Below i have shared the code.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());            

//      StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, "http://headers.jsontest.com/", listener, errorListener);

        String url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value";

         JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, listener, errorListener);
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

---

```
Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("","Success Response: " + response.toString()); 
        }
    };


    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                Log.d("","Error Response code: " +  error.networkResponse.statusCode);
            }
        }
    };
```

Why am i getting this exception and how to resolve this exception.

```
05-08 16:02:57.116: E/AndroidRuntime(16845): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectInputStream
05-08 16:02:57.116: E/AndroidRuntime(16845):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:398)
05-08 16:02:57.116: E/AndroidRuntime(16845):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:157)
05-08 16:02:57.116: E/AndroidRuntime(16845):    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:85)
```

---

```
/**
         * Reads the header off of an InputStream and returns a CacheHeader object.
         * @param is The InputStream to read from.
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static CacheHeader readHeader(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            CacheHeader entry = new CacheHeader();

            int magic = readInt(is);
            if (magic != CACHE_MAGIC) {
                // don't bother deleting, it'll get pruned eventually
                throw new IOException();
            }
            entry.key = readString(is);
            entry.etag = readString(is);
            if (entry.etag.equals("")) {
                entry.etag = null;
            }
            entry.serverDate = readLong(is);
            entry.ttl = readLong(is);
            entry.softTtl = readLong(is);
            **entry.responseHeaders = readStringStringMap((ObjectInputStream) is);**                                            return entry;
        }
```

The italics part in the code which in Volley which is wrong why it wrong.

Comment: From the logcat output it's obvious that you use a `FileInputStream` instance as it would be an `ObjectInputStream`. Investigate (and share) your `readHeader` method (`DiskBasedCache#398`) to find the problem.

Comment: entry.responseHeaders = readStringStringMap((ObjectInputStream) is);  This whts happening in line 398. the casting is wrongly done in Volley library. The correct way is new ObjectInputStream(is); is it a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you get is because you are trying to cast a `FileInputStream` instance to `ObjectInputStream`, but this is not the way it works, you have to wrap it:

```
    final ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    entry.responseHeaders = readStringStringMap(os);
```

The exception says that your `is` parameter is actually a `FileInputStream`, but you don't have to deal with that: it's enough to know that it is an `InputStream` implementation, so you can use it in the `ObjectInputStream` constructor.

Comment: why Android has not fixed it? Am i using the correct library

Comment: Fix what??? It's written in the API doc of the input streams what their purpose is, and how to use them. You were using them in an incorrect way, so an exception was thrown, and it's your job to correct it (use the classes in the way they are meant to).

Comment: Sorry that was how android volley was using it. it was not my code it's was code in Volley library. I have updated the question with full code in volley library.

Comment: Sorry, I see now. Than it's their responsibility to fix it, they shouldn't have let the clients pass anything but ObjectOutputStream in the first place. But if you call the method containing this snippet from your code, you could pass a wrapped ObjectOutputStream parameter to it, and your problem is solved. You could also modify the library code if you have access to its source, but that is a worst case scenario :)

Comment: my worry was so much used code how did they make such a mistake. So only wanted to double conform it before making the changes. thanks for discussing the issue.

Comment: It turns out your worries were legit, they should have pay more attention. Adding an overwhelming comment about the method usage does not solve the problem, they have to put more strict type restriction on their input parameters. You should file a bug report for this issue, if they have any bug tracking platform out there.